# Unintentionally moved all my home directories to desktop screen

Tags: command-line, home-directory

I am new to using command line and wanted to rename all directories in my home directory to be lower case (`Desktop` → `desktop`, `Music` → `music`, etc).

After I restarted the computer, the files and desktop background had reverted to default and there was now a second "Desktop" directory present which contained nothing.

I deleted it, and now all directories in my home directory are visibly present on my desktop. I'm sure this is easily resolved, I'm just curious as to what I actually did here.

Comment: Please ere-create that `Desktop` directory lets see if they will return

Comment: did so, but seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Ok try this go to `/home/$USER/.config/user-dirs.dirs` in there modify the names to reflect your change

Comment: Do this move the folders from desktop back to the new `desktop`, then modify the names in the `/home/$USER/.config/user-dirs.dirs` to say `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/desktop"` and let see if that fixes the issue

Comment: **Why are you renaming the standard folders in Ubuntu?** You're going to break stuff that way.